onEdit script runs first part but not second part
I have one sheet where I want to add a date depending on entries into two different cells. So when a person adds their name, it adds a start date, and when they change status to complete, it adds an end date.
I had them in separate scripts initially and noticed whichever one was second in the list worked but the other one didn't. So I tried to combine them into one and now the first part (name adds start date) works but the second part doesn't.
So far, I can't figure out what I've done wrong but this is all a new experience! Thank you for any help!
function onEdit (e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();

//set start date when owner is entered  
  if (range.getColumn() == 3 && sheet.getName() === "Projects"){
    var ownerCell = range.getValue();

    if (ownerCell !=="") {
      var startdateCell = range.offset(0,5);
      var currentDate = new Date();
      startdateCell.setValue(currentDate);
    } else {
      range.offset(0,5).clearContent();
    }
    
//set end date when completed is selected
  if (range.getColumn() == 6 && sheet.getName() === "Projects"){
    var statusCell = range.getValue();

    if (statusCell ==="Complete") {
      var enddateCell = range.offset(0,3);
      var finishDate = new Date();
      enddateCell.setValue(finishDate);
    } else {
      range.offset(0,3).clearContent();
    }

  }
}
}


The reason why the second part doesn't work is because if (range.getColumn() == 6 && sheet.getName() === "Projects") is inside if (range.getColumn() == 3 && sheet.getName() === "Projects").
To resolve this, move if (range.getColumn() == 6 && sheet.getName() === "Projects") outside so both conditions are checked independently.
Full Code:
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();

  if (range.getColumn() == 3 && sheet.getName() === "Projects") {
    var ownerCell = range.getValue();

    if (ownerCell !== "") {
      var startdateCell = range.offset(0, 5);
      var currentDate = new Date();
      startdateCell.setValue(currentDate);
    } else {
      range.offset(0, 5).clearContent();
    }
  }

  if (range.getColumn() == 6 && sheet.getName() === "Projects") {
    var statusCell = range.getValue();

    if (statusCell === "Complete") {
      var enddateCell = range.offset(0, 3);
      var finishDate = new Date();
      enddateCell.setValue(finishDate);
    } else {
      range.offset(0, 3).clearContent();
    }
  }
}

Output:

Note: For visual output only.



OH WOW! That's amazing! Thank you so much! I appreciate your help.

You're welcome! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the check icon on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer.

Here's the code rewritten so that it observes these onEdit(e) best practices:
function onEdit(e) {
  if (![3, 6].includes(e.range.columnStart) || e.range.getSheet().getName() !== 'Projects') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart === 3) e.range.offset(0, 5).setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);
  if (e.range.columnStart === 6) e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(e.value === 'Complete' ? new Date() : null);
}

See Array.includes.
